# DOM parse xml file without converting entity references

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am writing a parser for an xml file which will contains special characters, for example

```
<name>You &amp; me &#174;</name>
```

The dom parser will, by default, parse this value to "You & me ®".
However what I want the string is

```
You &amp; me &#174;
```

Is there any way I can do this?
Thanks

Comment: Which parser are you using? And do you need the exact string or can you just re-encode the strings after you get them from the parser?

Comment: I am using DOM, the reason is that I will to return those &#174; to my client, they will display it to customer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DOM for parsing, see the [DocumentBuilderFactory.setExpandEntityReferences()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setExpandEntityReferences%28boolean%29) method.

By default, this setting is `true` meaning that entities are expanded out automatically.  If you turn this off, you will be able to read the entities from the DOM - in this case you won't just get one big text node from a parent element, but you will get text nodes interleaved with entity nodes.